# How to Get the details after the space in REGEXP_SUBSTR in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I just want some help in my script. I have a 2 types of values in my data the first one is

> first-order, Delivery Date: 04/18/2020 AM, OOS: Find similar item

The other one is

> third-order, Delivery Date:04/19/2020 AM, OOS: Find similar item

I already get the "04/19/2020" after the word "Delivery Date:" in the second example.
My problem is how can I get the date "04/18/2020" after the word "Delivery Date:" in the first value.
Here is what I came up to get the value of the second example.

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_name,'Date:([[:alnum:]]+\.?){1,10}........?') from mytable
```

What other way to get the value after the space or additional function in my existing script.
Thank you. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```regex
Delivery Date:\s*(\S+)
```

This matches the contents after delivery date, also allowing for an optional space separator after the colon.

SQL code:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'Delivery Date:\s*(\S+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS "date"
FROM mytable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo